# How do I change sheet name dynamically in excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a VBA code which one of the line looks like this

> analysisSheet.Cells(i, tempCell).FormulaR1C1 =
>   "=AVERAGE('Data1'!R[-2]C[-7])"

I want to be able to change 'Data1' sheet so that user can dynamically choose the sheet he/she wants to analyze. For example, if user chooses 'Data2" Then the code will run like this.

> analysisSheet.Cells(i, tempCell).FormulaR1C1 =
>   "=AVERAGE('Data2'!R[-2]C[-7])"

I tried creating string variable and putting that in, but it didn't work.

Does anyone have any idea?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you want to user to change the name? Is it done in a VBA module ?

Comment: Show what you wrote when you tried using a string variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a string variable, e.g., SheetName, as you described:

```
Dim SheetName As String
SheetName = "Data3"
analysisSheet.Cells(i, tempCell).FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE('" & SheetName & "'!R[-2]C[-7])"
```